# java process eats only 1 cpu core

Tags: java, maven, jvm, jvm-arguments

i run my program using maven with the following command:

```
mvn exec:java -Dexec.mainClass="some.path.to.my.class"
```

on a Linux multi-cpu server. when i check the CPU usage, i see that java eats only 1 CPU core.
i read somewhere that setting the `-server` parameter could help.

what parameters do i have to set and how can i pass them using the `mvn exec:java` command?

Comment: You could try multithreading to use more than a core in java

Comment: it depends upon how many concurrently running threads an application have.

Comment: @AsierAranbarri so how can i do multithreading? do i have to put it into the code? cause i'm using external libraries dedicated to run also on a cluster and they should have it already inside.

Comment: Multithreading is nothing more than executing multiple threads running concurrently. These threads will start consuming more than a core.

Comment: If you don't know assume you're not: there's only a few things I know of that attempt to automatically parallise serial code and I don't think any of them have made it into Java yet. If your code isn't creating things that are able to be run off independantly on an arbitrary processor then don't be surprised if that's not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would set it in the commandlineArgs section of the configuration in your pom, as described in the [documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/exec-mojo.html)

eg:

```
 <build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>exec</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <executable>maven</executable>
      <commandlineArgs>-server</commandlineArgs>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
</plugins>
```

Although I'm not at all sure this is your problem - have you definitely written multithreaded code? You don't need to run the JVM in server mode to use multiple threads.

Comment: to do it from the command line it would just be -Dexec.args="-server"

Comment: thx for answer, but using the commandline parameters didn't help with the 1 core only problem

Comment: OK...as I asked, are you sure you have multithreaded code? Have you used Thread / Executor / ExecutorService anywhere in your code?

Comment: i'll try to look for it, it is an open source cluster program (apache mahout) which should have use it already itself.

Answer (score 1):

Processor affinity allows you to bind threads or processes to specific CPU cores. 
Java doesn’t have native support for processor affinity but we can set a process affinity using the [taskset](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/458640/cpu-reservation-and-affinity-using-taskset-and-isolcpus-kernel-parameter-with-jv) command. Say we have a Java process running and we want to pin it to a specific CPU. 
please see following links for more details and find how do this:
[cpu pinning java](https://www.chrisnewland.com/cpu-pinning-java-threads-with-jstack-and-taskset-380)